# Transfering a repo - no request shows up

Tags: github

I am trying to transfere a repository to another account.

It just says:

```
Transfer ownership

This repository is being transferred to <user name>
```

And in the top of the page it says:

```
Repository transfer to <user name> requested
```

Do you know how to accept a transfere?

Comment: Same issue. I don't see any notifications of any sort

Comment: Apparently, notifications are sent over mails. See this thread -> https://github.com/silverwind/cidr-regex/issues/6